# Django Tinymce file manager

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-filebrowser

I need a file manager for Django Tinymce.

I have tried Django filebrowser, but I can't get it to work. It shows a button next to the "Image URL" feld, but when I click it nothing shows up. How do it make it work?

Or... is there a better alternative?

Kind Regards,

Marian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2 Marian:**

Module for integration TinyMCE/images plugin into a python project.
For Django & Image Manager 1.1 beta1.

Installation

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Copy tinymce folder to your Django project root folder.

Add to main urls.py these strings:

```
(r'^static/js/tiny_mce/plugins/images/connector/python/', include('tinymce.images.urls')),
```

'static/js/tiny_mce' should be changed to your TinyMCE url.

If you work with development server, these lines should be added:

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': 'D:\dev\djcode\mysite\media'}),

(r'^uploads/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': 'D:\dev\djcode\mysite\uploads'}),
```

'D:\dev\djcode\mysite' should be changed to absolute path of your Django project folder.

Problems

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1. Multiple files upload doesn't work because flash doesn't send COOKIES. Django work with sessions through cookies by default. So we are waiting for flash module fixes.
2. As for now - only in English.

Comment: Can't make it work. I have copied the tinymce folder into my project, but it brakes it. I now get an error like this `Could not import blablabla. Error was: No module named widgets`

Comment: Maybe it would be better for you to post your project settings for Filebrowser, believe me it's better than other ones. If it doesn't work for you it just means your configuration is not quite right.

Comment: I'm actually going to write my own. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Marian I am having the same problem as you had once regarding the file manager for TinyMCE in django. Just wanted to know if you have written one yourself. Could you give some pointers on how I could go about doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [at the Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/) or the [Tinymce Image Mangager](http://dustweb.ru/en/projects/tinymce_images/).

Comment: I found this [link](http://dustweb.ru/files/python-images.zip) on your second link. It is written for django, but the install instructions are written in Russian and I can't figure how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Django-tinymce-filebrowser

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django-tinymce-filebrowser

Its allow to manage images and files from tinyMCE